# Filtering Pivot Table Items by Referencing Cell String Values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I am trying to filter a pivot table using the string value from a number of cells, which are stored in an array variable LTmonth(). However, when I plug this array variable into the code below, it doesn't read the array values for some reason and won't filter the values stored in that array.

One thing I noted, when I change LTmonth into an actual value of the filter such as shown below, the code works perfectly:

"If ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONTH").PivotItems(j) = **"JAN-2016"** Then"

Given that the cell values exactly match the filter items in the pivot table, how do I make the two values match each other? I've looked everywhere for an answer, but the answers I've found didn't help solve my problem. This is the closest I've gotten to making the code work, but I'm not sure why the variable array isn't working.

```
Sub Filter()

    Dim i, j, z, monthcount As Integer
    monthcount = 8

    Dim LTmonth() As String
    ReDim LTmonth(monthcount)

    For i = 1 To monthcount
        LTmonth(i) = ActiveSheet.Range("P2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
    Next i


    For j = 1 To ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONTH").PivotItems.Count
        For z = 1 To monthcount
            If ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONTH").PivotItems(j) = LTmonth(z) Then
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONTH").PivotItems(j).Visible = True
            Else
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONTH").PivotItems(j).Visible = False
            End If
        Next z
    Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: Debug the code using `F8` to see what's in array. And to compare two strings use `InStr`.

Comment: How do you compare the string value of the filter items? I think this might be the case since the formatting of the date in the filter may be different than the actual format of the item.

Answer (score 0):

See if that does what you are trying to achieve.

```
Sub Filter()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField

    Dim i, j, z, monthcount As Integer
    monthcount = 8

    Dim LTMonth() As String
    ReDim LTMonth(monthcount)

    For i = 1 To monthcount
        LTMonth(i) = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("P2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value, "mmm-yyyy")
    Next i

    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Month")
    pf.ClearAllFilters
    For j = 1 To pf.PivotItems.Count
        For z = 1 To monthcount
            If ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONTH").PivotItems(j) = LTMonth(z) Then
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONTH").PivotItems(j).Visible = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next z
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, the filter items are in uppercase format (ex. JAN-2016) so I'm not sure if the format statement you added will work. The cells that were referenced already correct this capitalization using "=UPPER(TEXT(A4,"MMM-YYYY))". Also, I am unable to use the ClearAllFilters statement as there is another pivot table below so not all the filters will be able to checked as they will overlap. I'm trying to circumvent this problem by having it check and uncheck one by one the filter values that are referenced in the cells.

Comment: So I just found out that my coworker is changing the original pivot filter names to the "MMM-YYYY" format after he filters for them in the pivot table (not in the raw data). So originally, the filter items are written in the format of 1/1/2015, but he would go and rename the filter item as JAN-2015 instead. The filter item would read "JAN-2015" instead of "1/1/2015". How does this change things, if any?

Comment: In that case try LTMonth(i) = UCase(Format(ActiveSheet.Range("P2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value, "mmm-yyyy")) and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it didn't work. I see in the code that when the pivot item is renamed, it produces the following code: [ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONTH").PivotItems( _ "3/1/2015").Caption = "MAR-2015"]. I see that the function ".Caption" is used. Not sure if this helps...

Comment: Then try If ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONTH").PivotItems(j).Caption = LTMonth(z) Then

Comment: It still works if I use the name of one of the filter items (e.x: If ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONTH").‌​PivotItems(j).Captio‌​n = **"JAN-2016"** Then), but won't work if I use LTMonth(z). I've even replaced all the values of LTMonth(z) as absolute string values and not even in date format anymore. I've tried it with the apostrophe (') in front of the cell value as well. Running out of ideas at this point.

Comment: Have you tried -  LTMonth(i) = CStr(UCase(Format(ActiveSheet.Range("P2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value, "mmm-yyyy")))